# not understanding why this code is not working

Tags: php, html, session

im new to sessions but from what i see it complicated to apply `<input>` with them.  can you please look at this code and tell me why its not working. i had it working earlier then it died on me. the function of the program is to fill out a form and have it verified for legit information using regular expressions, i just need help with getting the sessions to save the data.

```
<?php session_start(); ?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>regex</title>


</head>

<body>

<?php

$fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];

$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];


print<<<form

<form method="post"  action="">

  <input type ="text"
             name="fname"
             value="">

    <input type ="submit">

</form>

form;

$_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;

 print $_SESSION['fname'];


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Step 1: tell us how you're expecting it to function.

Comment: Gah, too many concurrent editors! :) Sorry for the rollbacks, just trying to get it into a state of readability.

Comment: @Timothy - Keep an eye on how you're editing your post, you keep overriding formatting edits that are helping to make your post more readable.

Comment: ooops... How you do uncommunity wiki this thread?

Comment: It has something to do with the edits... doesn't it?

Comment: You cannot revert a community wiki.

Comment: Probably not a big deal; I'm guessing the OP is looking more for a solution and less for SO rep - the way it should be :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timothy,
Change your code so that it checks if the session/request is empty or not

Something like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['fname'])){
  $fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
}else if(isset($_SESSION['fname'])){
  $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
}
```

Comment: sorry it took so long the person that referred me to this site just showed me how to mark.

Comment: Not a problem - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You are reading $fname from $_REQUEST, then overwriting it with the value from $_SESSION, then putting it back to $_SESSION. So far, it should work as designed :) What are you trying to do? If you want to set the $_SESSION variable with the value received through $_REQUEST, leave out the second "$fname=" line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['fname'])) {
    $_SESSION['fname'] = '';  // default value
}
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
}

print<<<form

…

form;

print $_SESSION['fname'];
```